# Android Image Magick TIFF group4 Compression

Tags: android, compression, imagemagick, tiff

I've downloaded the [image-lib-magic](https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick) and I'm trying to convert a JPEG image into TIFF group4 compression. But the only command that does not work is `CompressionType.Group4Compression`. I'm trying to put it as argument in the `ImageInfo` and `MagickImage` objects. But after job completed the image result doesn't have the group4 compression.

My doubt is about the sequence of metthod called. To compress a TIFF Group4 image, what I need to do? I tried many types and order, but without success.

Please help me, to finish my project it's the only thing that is missing....
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could it be that ImageMagick is rejecting it because G4 compression is for 1-bpp images and JPEG produces 8/24bpp images?

Comment: But I'm compressing the image in monochrome format... So I think that there is a sequence of methods to be called. Because this format I can get in jmagick to.

Comment: Monochrome can be more than 1 bit per pixel. I don't use ImageMagick, but I'm just trying to find you a cause. G4 is only Bitonal (1-bpp), monochrome JPEG is 8-bpp.